# seemingly equal objects are not equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I am trying to test a Redux action but im getting this error in my terminal:
**AssertionError: expected { type: 'LOG_IN', email: 'email' } to equal { type: 'LOG_IN', email: 'email' } + expected - actual**

**The problem:** The two objects seem to be equal, they have same attributes with same values. I expect them to be equal. But they are reported as not equal.

myActions.js

```
import { LOG_IN,LOG_OUT } from './actionTypes';

export function logIn(email) {
 return {
   type: LOG_IN,
   email: email
 };
}
```

userReducer.test.js

```
import * as actions from '../actions/userActions';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import user from '../reducers/userReducer';


describe('user login reducer test', () => {
   it('should update initialState to include email', () => {
    const email = 'email'
    const expectedAction = {
    type: LOG_IN,
    email: 'email'
 }

    const result = actions.logIn(email);
    expect(result).to.equal(expectedAction);
  })
 })
```

actiontypes.js

```
export const LOG_IN = 'LOG_IN';
export const LOG_OUT = 'LOG_OUT';
```

Comment: Change the title to reflect the problem more accurately. Like "Redux - seemingly equal objects are not equal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are using [`Chai`](http://www.chaijs.com/) for assertion, then you should be using the [`eql`](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) method

```
expect(result).to.eql(expectedAction);
```

If you want to use `Jest`, then you can use the [`toEqual`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/using-matchers.html#common-matchers) method

```
expect(result).toEqual(expectedAction);
```